# Multiple instance of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

is it possible to create multiple instances of hashmaps with same key? For example :

```
while(br.readLine != ""){
 HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  
 String[] Values = readLine.split(":");
  hm.put(1,Value[1]);  
  hm.put(2,Value[2);  
  hm.put(3,Value[3]);  
}
```

In this case, will new instance of hashmap will be created for each iteration of the loop or will it get overriden?

If it gets overriden, how to implement multiple instances of the map in this scenario?

Comment: I wish every java newbie had to donate $1 to charity for comparing strings using `==` or `!=` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new instance of `HashMap` will be created for each iteration of the loop and will be eligible for GC when the iteration ends because there are no references to it.

You could create a `List<HashMap<Integer, String>>` outside the loop and keep adding the newly created maps into this list in the loop so that they are accessible outside the loop as well.

PS : If by "overridden", you mean "overwritten", then "no", the old hashmap instance is not "reused". For each iteration, a new instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, will new instance of hashmap will be created for each iteration of the loop or will it get overriden?

New instance of Map created each time.

> If it gets overriden, how to implement multiple instances of the map in this scenario?

Not ovveriden. Multiple instances of  created.

Remember that whenever you use new keyword used, you are creating a new instance of the Class.

And they are not useful anyway once the loop terminated. Hopefully you are doing something on the hashmap, later in the loop.

Comment: Thank you down voter, but your comment is more valuable than vote.

Answer (score 0):

First you should move the map out from the `while` statement, otherwise at each iteration you create a new `Map` instance and consequently you lose the content put in the previous Map instance used.

I don't see really the point to create a Map instance for each line that contains a few values.
It seems an overhead.

To not overwrite the value associated to predefined keys, you could use a single map and have multiple `String` values associated to the key.
So you could use a `Map` of `List` of `String` instead of a `Map` of `String`.

If you have 3 constant keys as in your example you can initialize the List before the loop.
Otherwise you may instantiate the List dynamically.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();  

map.put(1, new ArrayList<String>());
map.put(2, new ArrayList<String>());
map.put(3, new ArrayList<String>());

while(br.readLine != nul){

  String[] values = readLine.split(":");

  map.get(1).add(values[0]);
  map.get(2).add(values[1]);
  map.get(3).add(values[2]);
}
```